# SafeAreaView No overload matches this call react native

Tags: reactjs, native, tsx, safeareaview

SafeAreaView showing error in tsx file .
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ViewProps | Readonly): SafeAreaView', gave the following error.
Type '{ children: Element; style: { flex: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'.

I tried it without giving flex as it shows error in flex:number ( Type '{ children: Element; style: { flex: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'.)

Comment: when i use styled component this error does not show